# SQL Dependency with SQL Server express 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005-express, sqldependency

Is it possible to use SQL Dependency with SQL Server Express 2005 which comes with VS 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article suggest that it will work fine as long as the express edition database is a named instance:

http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0605061&page=5

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It works fine with named instances as well as default instances, on any SKU (Express, Web, Developer, Standard, Enterprise and Data Center). You can read [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) to understand the underlying mechanism that powers SQL Dependency.

When you open a database using the connection string option AttachDBName you are using a [User Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264564%28SQL.90%29.aspx) (aka RANU). The user instances attaches the MDF file using and by default a newly attached database will disable Service Broker in the database. Because the Query Notifications use Service Broker to deliver the notification, it implies that a database with Service Broker disabled cannot create a notification subscription, unless it takes the necessary steps to re-enable Service Broker.